# How to setup Git with dev/stage/production branches to separates deployment tasks?

Tags: git, deployment, gitlab, branching-and-merging

I'm looking for a way to setup a branching strategy that separates deployment tasks from each other.

I recently read an article at http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/branching-best-practices.html

Based on this, I have created `dev` → `stage` → `production` branches in my project:

- `dev` — for QA
- `stage` — for preparing the release
- `production` — for code that's deployed to the production server.

**Here's what my workflow looks like right now:**

1. I create a `feature` branch from `stage`
2. I submit a Merge Request from the `feature` branch to `dev`
3. After QA, I send a Merge Request from the `feature` branch to `stage`
4. Upon release, I Merge Request `stage` to `production`

But I run into issues when Merge Conflicts occur between `feature` and `dev` branches. To address them, GitLab recommends merging all changes from `dev` into the `feature` branch. However, this seems counterproductive because, in step 3, I can't create a clean Merge Request from the `feature` branch to `stage` as it now contains all the changes from `dev`.

What should I do?

I've tried to make MR from `stage` to `feature`. But it also doesn't work because of conflicts between them.

Comment: What these Git Flow-esque articles often seem to recomment is to use `dev` to deal with feature branches (branch off and merge into) and then only deal with `dev` (not feature branches) when merging things to `stage`.

Comment: It’s difficult to skim this article but: “this is easily done by using feature and bug-fix branches and only merging them back to your development branch once they are tested.”—This seems to imply that you both branch off from (“merging them back”) and merge back to `dev`. You don’t branch off from `stage`.

Comment: @Guildenstern But if I go this way, how could I merge my feature branch to stage separately of dev changes?

Comment: Does the article say that you should do that?

Comment: @Guildenstern I assumed it is a healthy feature deployment scenario.

Comment: I’ve read the article instead of skimming it now. Staging → Stable → Production. Things should flow in that direction only. Feature branches should be created from Staging and then be merged into Staging. Then eventually Staging is merged into Stable. And then Stable into Production. As long as this workflow is not deviated from there will be no merge conflicts since the merges only go in certain directions.